# To append an Key:Value pair to my array element only once!

Tags: javascript

```
var people =[{title:'Alan', hasChild:true},
            {title:'Alice', hasDetail:true},
            {title:'Amos',},
            {title:'Alonzo'},
            {title:'Brad'},
            {title:'Brent'},    
            {title:'Billy'},    
            {title:'Brenda'},   
            {title:'Callie'},
            {title:'Cassie'},   
            {title:'Chris'}];
```

By default my array does not contain any key,value pair which is `header:'A'` , `header:'B'` , `header'C' so on... I add them at run time.

```
for (i = 0, len = people.length; i < len; i++) {
            var headerValue = people[i].header = people[i].title.charAt(0);
}
```

By doing this my array has a new key,value pair `'Header:'FirstLetter of the title'`.

```
var people =[{title:'Alan', hasChild:true, header:'A'},
                {title:'Alice', hasDetail:true,header:'A'},
                {title:'Amos',header:'A'},
                {title:'Alonzo',header:'A'},
                {title:'Brad',header:'B'},
                {title:'Brent',header:'B'}, 
                {title:'Billy',header:'B'}, 
                {title:'Brenda',header:'B'},    
                {title:'Callie',header:'C'},
                {title:'Cassie',header:'C'},    
                {title:'Chris',header:'C'}];
```

I don't want to add the header:value to all the elementes, If i add the header:value to the element one whose title starts with 'A', then the rest of the elements whose title start's with A should be ignored. **I want the array in this format.**

```
var people =[{title:'Alan', hasChild:true, header:'A'},
                    {title:'Alice', hasDetail:true,},
                    {title:'Amos'},
                    {title:'Alonzo'},
                    {title:'Brad',header:'B'},
                    {title:'Brent'},    
                    {title:'Billy'},    
                    {title:'Brenda'},   
                    {title:'Callie',header:'C'},
                    {title:'Cassie'},   
                    {title:'Chris'}];
```

**My updated code....**

```
    function SortByName(x,y) {        
      return ((x.LastName == y.LastName) ? 0 : ((x.LastName > y.LastName) ? 1 : -1 ));    
    }

    function RenderPatientSearchData(PatientSearchResponse){
        var PatientSearchData = JSON.parse(PatientSearchResponse);
        var results = PatientSearchData['PatientSearchResult'];
        results.Patient.sort(SortByName);
        rowData = [];

        var prevHeader = '';
        for (i = 0, len = results.Patient.length; i < len; i++) {
            var headerValue = results.Patient[i].header = results.Patient[i].LastName.charAt(0);    
                if (headerValue !== prevHeader) {      
                    headerValue = results.Patient[i].header = results.Patient[i].LastName.charAt(0);    
             }
            prevHeader = headerValue;

....... some code... 

}
```

Comment: I think the original format is _better_. Your proposed format leaves individual elements without all their proper contextual information, simply because they happen to be found next to a certain other element in some array somewhere? Poor.

Comment: Also, show us what you tried so far. This is not rentacoder.com!

Comment: @john your question title is not very descriptive (and your question is not either, actually). Please try to think of how others read your questions and have to make sense of it. Additionally, try to think of a solution yourself before asking for it right away. Your previous question was posted and answered 10 minutes ago. I cannot imagine that have *really* tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Aron Rotteveel: I will keep this in mind, i tried this for two days... today i have a demo so i need to sort it out...

Comment: Why aren't you using the format: `{ Alan: { hasChild:true }, Alice: { hasDetail: true }` ?

Comment: It has been like this, i don't have access to backend code to change... else i would have appeneded the value there itself instead of breaking the head in front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the header value within the loop:

```
var prevHeader = '';
for (i = 0, len = people.length; i < len; i++) {
    var headerValue = people[i].title.charAt(0);
    if (headerValue !== prevHeader) {
      people[i].header = headerValue;
    }
    prevHeader = headerValue;
}
```

Note: to make this work, your `people` array has to be sorted beforehand

Comment: I just updated my working code, do you think it has any mistakes... it still adds header:value to all elements

Comment: @John: I can't tell without code. Why don't you try to make a example @ http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Kooilnc: I have updated my code in main post... and thanks for the fiddle.. .i am looking into it